# Unable to Ping a server IP which is outside the subnet mask

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

This is the setup we are having:

2 servers which are in HA[High Availability Network] are configured with the following IP address
Server 1 --> 10.54.48.x and 
Server 2 --> 10.54.49.x.

There is a Logical IP which binds to both of these server with IP address 10.54.49.y (binds to Server 1 or server 2 whichever is Active)

We can configured all the IP addresses here with subnet mask 255.255.255.0

But the router present is configured with /23 subnet which makes the default gateway as 10.54.48.1

Now I am trying to ping Server 1 IP 10.54.48.x from a outside network, say 10.54.80.x and the ping is fine
But pinging to Server 2 IP(10.54.49.x) (or) the Logical IP(10.54.49.y) is failing.

Question: Is setting the subnet masks of the servers to /24 causing this issue?

Comment: Why the mix of /23 and /24?

Comment: Server 2 (10.54.49.x) can't use 10.54.48.1 as it's default gateway because 10.54.48.1 is not in the same subnet as Server 2.

Comment: @Chopper3, It was a misconfiguration from our side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is: yes.
If there is no proper routing between the subnets you can not reach the other subnet. That's the whole purpose of subnetting.